# jquery: watch script on upload

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, progress-bar, jquery-confirm

I am executing an ajax script to upload files and the PHP file that those the upload not only uploads but also executes MySQL queries.

My question is: is it possible to have a progress bar not only for the file upload but for the entire script? If possible with separated messages for each "Step" inside the php file.

```
Example (upload.php):
#Step 1
$message = "uploading file";

#Step 2
$message = "Creating Thumbnail";

#Step 3
$message = "Add to Database";
```

Comment: show loader gif when ajax request send, when response return (success) hide gif loader.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21694521/how-to-get-wait-loader-during-ajax-call

Comment: https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=jquery+upload+progress+bar&oq=jquery+upload+progress+bar&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.3890j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: That I know. My question is different.

I have a php file with several steps and I want a message to be shown a div everytime it goes to a different step.

    Example (upload.php):
#Step 1
$message = "uploading file";

#Step 2
$message = "Creating Thumbnail";

#Step 3
$message = "Add to Database";

Comment: AFAIK you can only see the amount of data uploaded. Is your upload really so slow that's necessary to tell the user this much detail?